# How to get file system errno on Linux

Tags: php, error-handling

I see that `file_put_contents` function is returning `FALSE` but is it possible to know the error (`errno`) returned from the system call from Linux kernel?

There could be many reasons for failure (which could even be device or driver dependent). So I want to know the exact error reason.

`file_put_contents` simply returns `FALSE` on failure.

What I want would be equivalent to C `errno` or the `perror` C function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results can be kind of ambiguous, but the closest equivalent to `errno` in PHP is the [`error_get_last`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) function.